# Extracting data from emails reveals only the data of the last day only the "subject name" took place after printing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, imaplib

```
import imaplib
import email
import getpass
import pandas as pd
#The usual process of email reading:
username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
password = 'xxxxxxxxxx' 

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
mail.login(username, password)
mail.select("inbox")
#determining the needed subject:
result, numbers = mail.search(None, '(Subject "*warning")')
uids = numbers[0].split()
uids = [id.decode("utf-8") for id in uids ]
result, messages = mail.fetch(','.join(uids) ,'(RFC822)')
#creating the lists to fetch the following:
body_list =[]
to_list = []
date_list = []
from_list = [] 
subject_list = []
for _, message in messages[::2]:
    email_message = email.message_from_bytes(message)
    email_subject = email.header.decode_header(email_message['Subject'])[0]
for part in email_message.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain" :
        body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
        body = body.decode("utf-8")
        body_list.append(body)
    else:
        continue
    if isinstance(email_subject[0],bytes):
        decoded = email_subject.decode(errors="ignore")
        subject_list.append(decoded)
                 
    else:
        subject_list.append(email_subject[0])
        date_list.append(email_message.get('date'))
        fromlist = email_message.get('from')
        from_list.append(fromlist)
        tolist =  email_message.get('to')             
        to_list.append(tolist)  

date_list = pd.to_datetime(date_list)
date_list = [item.isoformat(' ')[:-6]for item in date_list]
a = {'Date':date_list,'Sender':from_list,'Receiver':to_list,'Subject':subject_list, 
'Body':body_list}
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
data.to_csv('emails.csv',index=False)

data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\emails.csv").transpose()

print(data)
```

The extracted data frame is for the last day the subject name had appeared only and the other days are not recorded which make it useful, I doubt that there is something wrong when it comes to lists, kindly help me to fix this "Thanks in advance".

Comment: Can you print email_message?

Comment: @keramat Printing the message includes all the required subjects normally

Comment: So, print part in the begin of for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Printing part in the beginning of the loop has solved the issue.

Thanks to [Keramat's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72065370/extracting-data-from-emails-reveals-only-the-data-of-the-last-day-only-the-subj/72590236#comment127341425_72065370)